# Limit directive to specific host (component) in Angular

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Is is possible to limit which component can have custom directive?

**For example:**

```
@Directive({ 
    selector: '[myHighlight]', 
    host: "my-component" //!!!!!!!!!
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {  //el is my-component - can not be nothing else !!!!
       el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}

@Component({selector: "my-component"})...
```

**Use case:**
I would like to write directive for specific third-party component. I will use that third-party component properties, so directive on another component wouldn't make any sense and would throw errors.

That means that `myHighlight` on `div` would be ignored.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I know this question is a couple months old, but you can do this in the selector.  The selector property is just a css selector, so you should be able to do something like:

```
@Directive({ 
    selector: 'my-component[myHighlight]'
})
```

And that would match only `my-component` tags with `myHighlight` attribute.  If you tried to apply the `myHighlight` attribute to, lets say, a `div` tag, you'd end up getting an error in the console like:

```
Can't bind to 'myHighlight' since it isn't a known property of 'div'
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need use host. In `host`, you can write what events you want to listen and some other properties like attribute binding. About this, you can read there [Angular Directives](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive)

In your case, you can check where you bind your directive like in this example:

```
@Directive({ 
    selector: '[myHighlight]', 
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) { 
       if (el.nativeElement.tagName === "MY-COMPONENT"){
           el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
       } 
    }
}
```